# regarding the usage of cast function to process time information in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There is a dataframe shown as follows, it has two columns.

```
df.show()
|                Time|             MinTime|
|2019-11-19 23:00:...|2019-11-19 23:00:...|
|2019-11-19 23:15:...|2019-11-19 23:00:...|
|2019-11-19 23:30:...|2019-11-19 23:00:...|

root
 |-- Time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MinTime: string (nullable = true)

df.show(truncate=False)
|                Time|             MinTime|
|2019-11-19 23:00:000000|2019-11-19 23:00:000000|
|2019-11-19 23:15:000000|2019-11-19 23:00:000000|
|2019-11-19 23:30:000000|2019-11-19 23:00:000000|
```

After I use the following line of code to process the above column, the values for column `Offset` are all null. Based on the values in `Time` and `MinTime`, the difference should not be null for all the rows. May I know the reason for this?

```
df= df.withColumn('Offset',((col('Time').cast('long') - col('MinTime').cast('long'))))
df.show()
|                Time|             MinTime|         Offset|
|2019-11-19 23:00:...|2019-11-19 23:00:...|           null|
|2019-11-19 23:15:...|2019-11-19 23:00:...|           null|
|2019-11-19 23:30:...|2019-11-19 23:00:...|           null|

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MinTime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Offset: long (nullable = true)

df.show(truncate=False)
|                Time|                  MinTime|          Offset|
|2019-11-19 23:00:000000|2019-11-19 23:00:000000|           null|
|2019-11-19 23:15:000000|2019-11-19 23:00:000000|           null|
|2019-11-19 23:30:000000|2019-11-19 23:00:000000|           null|
```

Comment: can you printSchema please? also post `dfr.show(truncate=False)` for us to reproduce the problem

Comment: @anky, I have updated the original post as you suggested.

Comment: you have strings and not timestamp, hence you get nulls, I believe the below answer has got you covered.

Comment: @anky, thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your schema of your `df`, if the columns type is `String` it has to be converted to `timestamp` first

You can use `to_timestamp` function to convert the datatype to `timestamp` first as

```
date_format = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'

df.withColumn('Offset',
              (f.to_timestamp('Time', date_format).cast('long') - f.to_timestamp('MinTime').cast('long'))) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|Time               |MinTime            |Offset|
+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|2019-11-19 23:00:00|2019-11-19 23:00:00|0     |
|2019-11-19 23:15:00|2019-11-19 23:00:00|900   |
|2019-11-19 23:30:00|2019-11-19 23:00:00|1800  |
+-------------------+-------------------+------+
```

Please make sure to use the correct date format.